# How does while work in this particular case?

Tags: c, while-loop

i wanted to know how while worked in this particular code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main(){
    int count=0;    

    fork();
    printf("PID: %d\nCounter: %d\n",getpid(),++count);
    sleep(1);

    while(1);
}
```

I've only used while (or do while) with code inside the loop, never used it outside of the loop so i don't understand how this could work. Thanks for the time and patience.

Comment: Where did you see that code? It's just a while statement with no way to break it's infinite state, and so it stays infinite and checks the condition of true each cycle.

Comment: What do you think it does ?

Comment: I'm studying Operating Systems and i've seen an exercise from a friend of mine so i tried to do it and this is the result which it appears to be correct. I know what the code does i just don't get it how he is repeating the code that it is outside of the loop. It's like it is doing a do-while loop

Comment: What is the output? It looks naively like it should just print twice, leaving both parent and child stuck in their respective infinite loops.

Comment: You are looking for the description of a _null statement_.

Comment: The `while` has nothing to do with any actual code repeating here. Take a look at [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(system_call))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know what the code does i just don't get it how he is repeating the code that it is outside of the loop. It's like it is doing a do-while loop

The content outside the loop being "repeated" has nothing to do with the `while()` statement.

When the program starts running, it encounters the `fork();` statement. This creates a new process with a copy of the address space of the current process. Then, both continue executing concurrently. Each process executes its own `printf()` statement and displays its respective process ID.

Each process, in the end, encounters the `while(1);` statement. In C, any non-zero integer is equivalent to true when evaluating a condition. Hence, logically, `while(1);` is equivalent to `while(true);`. The semi-colon indicates that the body of the loop is empty.

Thus, when either of the process reaches the `while(1);` statement, it gets stuck in an infinite loop.

The `printf()` statement executing twice is due to the presence of two processes, and is not related to the `while(1);` statement.

Comment: I understand that with fork() i create a child process and that's why it looks like it is repeating itself (because it's executing the child)...but if i take out the fork() line of code it still repeats itself.

Comment: My bad, stupid me was compiling the wrong program...yes you are right it's because of the fork() creating another process. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

C's default conditions can be read at "is (condition) different from 0?".
In your case, that's "While (1) is different from 0", thus causes an infinite loop.
The program will indefinitely loop in this precise instruction (the While).

Comment: I'm studying Operating Systems and i've seen an exercise from a friend of mine so i tried to do it and this is the result which it appears to be correct. I know what the code does i just don't get it how he is repeating the code that it is outside of the loop. It's like it is doing a do-while loop

Comment: I'm sorry I misunderstood the question.
That is because of the semicolon you put after your `while` instruction. In C, putting a semicolon right after a condition will work the same as if you replaced the `{ }` with nothing. One way of seeing why it does, is considering the while will loop between your `)` and your `;` (which obviously does nothing).

Answer (score 0):

On linux, after compiling this program with gcc like this

```
gcc -o main main.c
```

And running the program like this

```
./main
```

If you try to print out the processes with the "main" name we have this.

```
$ ps aux | grep main
hoenir    3084 74.3  0.0   4160   676 pts/2    R+   19:34   0:04 ./main
hoenir    3085 74.3  0.0   4160    72 pts/2    R+   19:34   0:04 ./main
```

After the **fork()** call the program **spawns a child process** of the main process and thus, making the code left (after fork) execute in the parent and child in parallel, thus making the while loop, loop infinitely.
How the fellow user already said while(0) is like saying while(false) and viceversa while(1) or while(-1) or **other number that's different than 0** being while(true).

Comment: i don't know who downvote you but your answer helped me to understand fork() better so thanks :D. I gave you a upvote but duo to my reputation it's not recorded, sorry.

Comment: i up voted it.  What hoenir said is correct regarding what happens because of the use of `fork().

Answer (score -3):

```
while(1);
```

is essentially

```
while ( 1 == 1)
{
}
```

in C syntax you don't need code inside for `while, for, if` statements.

this code below is syntactically valid

```
if ( 1 == 1)
;
else
;
```

or

```
if ( 1 == 1 ) ; else ;
```

where the if statement would do nothing.  You can do the same with all the others- `while, for,` and so on.

Comment: More like, `while (1 != 0)`

Comment: I'm studying Operating Systems and i've seen an exercise from a friend of mine so i tried to do it and this is the result which it appears to be correct. I know what the code does i just don't get it how he is repeating the code that it is outside of the loop. It's like he is doing a do-while loop

Comment: So `while(0)` is equivalent to `while(0==0)`?

Comment: saying `while (1 != 0)`  is being low level minded and nit-picky, and does nothing to help answer the original question.

Comment: which is still `i wanted to know how while worked in this particular code... I've only used while (or do while) with code inside the loop`